# What's Difference Between Ubuntu Server (32bit) and Desktop (32bit) In Socket Programming

Tags: sockets, ubuntu, connection, desktop

I am working on a server/client based project.  I almost finished my server side code.

I develop the server app in EclipseCDT on Ubuntu Desktop, and everything just works fine.

But when deploy my app to a Ubuntu Server (I tried Server 10.04/10.10), the server app can start normally (waiting for connection), but the same client just cannot connect to the server.

I use Socket for receiving and sending data to/from the client.

Peter

P.S.: if I install `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` on my server machine, then everything works fine again.

===========================================================================

New Findings from the source code:

```
LabelStartBlocking:
int newScoketId = ::accept(socketId, 0, 0); // socketId == 3 ::accept is define in socket.h
                          // waiting for connection
LabelResume: // if new connection coming
// Do something with newSocketId
```

The behavior difference between Ubuntu Desktop and Server is:

On Ubuntu Desktop version, when the server starts, it is blocked at `LabelStartBlocking` with the socket routine `::accept`; and then if a new connection arrives, the server will resume at `LabelResume` and create a new socket connection using the return value `newSocketId`;

However, on Ubuntu Server version, when the server starts, it is also blocked at `LabelStartBlocking` with the socket routine `::accept`, but if a new connection arrives, the server won't resume at `LabelResume`, and the new socket connection CANNOT be created.

Can you guys help me out?

Peter

Comment: There are a few things you need to clear up: do the client program and the server program communicate properly when they are on the same box?  How do the programs specify the network address?  What does the network on which the client and server sit look like?  Put these in your questions and your source code and you might get reasonable answers.  The problem is not related to the difference between Ubuntu server and client.

Comment: The Socket connection code is from another team, and there is no documentation.  they cannot communicate even the server and client on the same box.  From my personal opinion, it might be some server/desktop configuration differences, because the same app, it works in Desktop but not work Server edition.

Comment: Hi antlersoft, I did find something in the source code.  Can you help me check it out? I added the new findings in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your attention.

I finally figured it out.

If there are more than one IP addresses for the same hostname (`/etc/hosts`), the old code will fail.

Example `/etc/hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost YourHostName
10.50.10.251 YourHostName
```

I traced the calling stack, and I found that, the IP address (10.50.10.251) passed to the program is translated into hostname, and then later the hostname is translated back to IP address (for binding), but a DIFFERENT one, that's why my server program cannot accept any client connection.

Hope it helps if any others have the similar issue.

Peter